# Data will not post to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

Here is the error I am getting:

```
SQL QUERY: INSERT INTO portfolio  (portImg,portTitle,portDesc,portCat,portSkill,portDate) VALUES (IMAGE, TITLE, sadasdasd, CAT, SKILL, 2014-02-15 08:53:10)
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
sadasdasd, CAT, SKILL, 2014-02-15 08:53:10)' at line 1
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $portImg =$_POST['portImg'];
    $portTitle =$_POST['portTitle'];
    $desc=$_POST['portDesc'];
    $portDesc = trim($desc);
    $portCat=$_POST['portCat'];
    $portSkill=$_POST['portSkill'];
    $portDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //very basic validation
    if($portImg ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
    }
    if($portTitle ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
    }

    if($portDesc ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the description.';
    }

    if($portCat ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
    }

    if($portSkill ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
    }

    if(!isset($error)){

        $query="INSERT INTO portfolio (portImg,portTitle,portDesc,portCat,portSkill,portDate) VALUES ($portImg, $portTitle, $portDesc, $portCat, $portSkill, $portDate)";


        echo "SQL QUERY: ".$query."<br />";


        if (!mysql_query($query))
        {
          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
        }

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=added');
            exit;

        } 

//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

It seems to be an issue caused by the Textarea (description).  It seems to be adding space before and after.  Any idea's?

Comment: wow, your code is very vulnerable for SQL injection. Please use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). If it's for courses, please notify your teacher that `mysql()` functions are officially deprecated. You can use either `mysqli()` functions or PDO (recommended).

Comment: good url may be it's help you http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for string fields, you have to enclose your value with `'` during insert... like:

```
SQL QUERY: INSERT INTO portfolio (portImg,portTitle,portDesc,portCat,portSkill,portDate)
VALUES ('IMAGE', 'TITLE', 'sadasdasd', 'CAT', 'SKILL', '2014-02-15 08:53:10')
```

So your php should be

```
INSERT INTO portfolio (portImg,portTitle,portDesc,portCat,portSkill,portDate)
VALUES ('$portImg', '$portTitle', '$portDesc', '$portCat', '$portSkill', '$portDate')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sanitizing your input. If you now put a double quote (") in one of your strings, your query-string is escaped and you get an invalid query.

Furthermore you are risking XSS-attacks, since anyone can input a query at will this way.

Answer (score 0):

Put `'sadasdasd'` in single quotes otherwise SQL assumes it to be a table column

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have entered apostroph in your description textarea

try use this

```
  $portTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($portTitle) ;
  $portDesc = mysql_real_escape_string($portDesc) ;
  ....
  .....//escape other variables also like that.
```

then use this :

```
 VALUES ('".$portImg."', '".$portTitle."', '".$portDesc."', '".$portCat."', '".$portSkill."', '".$portDate."')
```